# WPF DataGrid creating cellstyle overrides the default style

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I have a WPF DataGrid with autogenerated columns and i needed a very specific style in the cells as you can see in the next image.

[image]

To do this i have created CellStyles depending on the column index to get the desired colors composition, like this for headers.

```
datagrid.Columns[colIndex].HeaderStyle = new Style(typeof(DataGridColumnHeader));
datagrid.Columns[colIndex].HeaderStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(Control.BackgroundProperty, (SolidColorBrush)new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom(colors[colorIndex])));
datagrid.Columns[colIndex].HeaderStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(Control.BorderBrushProperty, (SolidColorBrush)new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom(colors[colorIndex])));
datagrid.Columns[colIndex].HeaderStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(Control.FontWeightProperty, FontWeights.Bold));
datagrid.Columns[colIndex].HeaderStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(Control.FontSizeProperty, 18.0));
```

like this for cells that require a specific color

```
datagrid.Columns[colIndex].CellStyle = new Style(typeof(DataGridCell));
datagrid.Columns[colIndex].CellStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(Control.BackgroundProperty, (SolidColorBrush)new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom(colors[colorIndex])));
datagrid.Columns[colIndex].CellStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(Control.BorderBrushProperty, (SolidColorBrush)new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom(colors[colorIndex])));
datagrid.Columns[colIndex].CellStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(TextBlock.FontWeightProperty, FontWeights.Bold));
datagrid.Columns[colIndex].CellStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(TextBlock.FontSizeProperty, 18.0));
datagrid.Columns[colIndex].IsReadOnly = true;
```

Everything is ok to this point, but, when i click on a row, the cells which style has been defined with "CellStyle = new Style" becomes all white, background and foreground, and i don't know how what i have to change to get the row data to be visible.

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define custom colours for the `HighlightBrushKey` and `HighlightTextBrushKey` brushes:

```
<DataGrid ...>
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Black"/>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    ...
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked perfectly. It was driving me crazy :D